# MVC 4 Custom route to search by ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have the following Route "ActionRoute" that i want to search by ID on a Table.
If i put the next route this doesn't show any data, just a blank table and empty view.
The ID that a want to search is **1** Its a decimal value.

**What am I wrong to be able to do and what should I correct so that it works well?**

Thanks

```
http://localhost:62357/ActionApprovers/Action/1
```

[Issue when search in Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1xpv.gif)

So i wrote a controller that i found in a tutorial but it doesn't work

```
public ActionResult Action(decimal? idprod)
{
        Entities db = new Entities();
        var s = from r in db.TB_RS_PROD
                select r;
        s = s.Where(b => b.IDPROD == idprod);
        return View(s);
}
```

And this is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcInventory.TB_RS_PROD>
@{

}

<html>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>ID PRODUCT</td>
        <td>PRODUCT NAME</td>
        <td>QUIANTITY</td>
        <td>DATE</td>
        <td>STATUS</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.IDPROD</td>
            <td>@item.PROD_NAME</td>
            <td>@item.QUANTITY</td>
            <td>@item.UPDATE_DATE</td>
            <td>@item.STATUS</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
</html>
```

This is Route on RouteConfig.cs

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ActionRoute",
            url: "ActionApprovers/{idprod}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ActionApprovers", action = "Action", idprod = 0 },
            constraints: new { beerid = @"\d+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

The Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

Comment: `public ActionResult Action(decimal? idprod)
{
    return View(model:idprod);
}` this is so incomplete. I don't see any model variable declared in your code. Will you include your full controller.

Comment: I'm new to MVC I just followed a tutorial but I don't know if this works https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299531/Custom-routes-for-MVC-Application

Comment: please include your full controller code. Did you try to debug? Put a breakpoint on `return View()` and see if `idprod` has a value.

Comment: @JerdineSabio I've updated my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching on a lot of sites i read about request with ID route.

```
public ActionResult Action(decimal? idprod)
{
    Entities db = new Entities();
    idprod = Convert.ToDecimal(Request["idprod"]); // This is the solution
    var s = from r in db.TB_RS_PROD
            select r;
    TempData["rt"] = idprod;
    s = s.Where(b => b.IDPROD == idprod);
    return View(s);
}
```